# Bad performance IIS 10 on win 2016 vs IIS 8 on 2012

Tags: azure, iis, performance-testing, windows-server-2016, iis-10

After having performance issues with a web application moving from a 2012 to a 2016 server i created a test setup. If have two machines set up on Azure. Both 4 cores & 8gb mem.

One machine is Win 2016 with IIS 10 the other Win 2012 with IIS 8.

I made a test with Jmeter (10 threads 30 loops) just letting the server return a jpg (2mb) over https. The Win 2012 has waaaay better the performance of the 2016 machine. Average response time 220ms (2012) vs 1100ms (2016).

Both machines are a default installation. I made no tweaks to IIS. Also tried to disable windows defender on 2016 machine but with no luck.

Anyone any idea why the performance of the 2016 machine is so much worse by default? Is there any setting i should try first?

Comment: "On Azure"? So did you count the time spent on the wire then? Your description above missed too many details, like where on the earth you ran JMeter. Therefore, it is not a valid question to discuss yet.

Comment: I run jmeter from my local machine. But i'm not interested in the response time of the requests but i want to know what is causing the huge performance difference between the two.

Comment: Interesting, I always had the feeling but never tested it. So I created two VMs in Azure (west-Europe), both F4s size (4 vcpu, 8 GB memory). One server Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter edition, the other Windows 2016 datacenter. For both I just installed the webserver (IIS) role, installed all updates, put a 2 MB jpg in the default website and restarted it. A simple load test with VSTS (west-europe) gives an average response time of 120 ms (2012R2) and 190 ms (1016). Not quite as bad as Paul but worse. Why?

Comment: Two years passed since the last comment here. @Frederic and/or Paul did you get any luck with your investigation of the downgraded performance of 2016vs2012?

Comment: Four years passed and I'm having the same issue, moved to a server with Windows Server 2022 Datacenter with IIS 10 and the speed is a lot slower than Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5. Any advice? All network issues have been ruled out.